# Multiple Joins and Subquery with Not Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to delete records from the BETA TABLE that doesn't exist in the ALPHA Table as well as excludes the records obtained by the inner join of CHARLIE and DELTA tables.

This is the query for A & B

```
SELECT B.* from ALPHA A right join 
BETA B ON  A.ID= B.ID
where A.ID is NULL
```

This gives me the records of BETA Table that don't exist in Alpha Table

[image: Resultant of Above Query]

Now my second query is

```
SELECT C.* FROM CHARLIE C INNER JOIN 
DELETE D ON 
C.ID=D.ID
```

This gives me the records from the inner join of CHARLIE AND DELTA

[image: Join of Charlie and Delta Tables]

I have tried using the query below, but it doesn't work and doesn't delete anything

```
DELETE B
From ALPHA A right join 
BETA B ON  A.ID = B.ID 
where A.ID is NULL AND NOT EXISTS

( SELECT C.* FROM CHARLIE C INNER JOIN DELTA D ON 
C.ID = D.ID WHERE B.ID = C.ID )
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What "doesn't work"?

Comment: It returns me an empty set.

Comment: As in "0 rows affected"? A delete statement doesn't normally return rows to the client

Comment: Please share data of A and B to better understand what you are looking for. Please share data of B before and after running this query.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it doesn't delete the record(s)

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur A and B have the same data except for some data that was deleted from A.

Comment: is it possible to share sample data of Alpha, Beta, Charlie and Delta

Comment: Is this **your actual query** because this should work (although I would really swap that `right join` for a `not exists`)?

Comment: @Charlieface yes this is my actual query. 

I have found the solution, B.ID = C.ID should've been C.ID = B.ID in the subquery after WHERE clause.

Comment: That doesn't make one ounce of sense `B.ID = C.ID` is the same as `C.ID = B.ID`

Comment: I swear, I only changed the order and it's working now

Answer (score 1):

I have solutions for you using "IN" and "Exists". Please check and let me know.

```
DECLARE @ALPHA TABLE( ID INT,VAL1 DECIMAL(18,2),VAL2 DECIMAL(18,2));
DECLARE @BETA TABLE( ID INT,VAL1 DECIMAL(18,2),VAL2 DECIMAL(18,2));
DECLARE @CHARLIE TABLE( ID INT,VAL1 DECIMAL(18,2),VAL2 DECIMAL(18,2));
DECLARE @DELTA TABLE( ID INT,VAL1 DECIMAL(18,2),VAL2 DECIMAL(18,2));
------------------------USING IN-------------------------------
DELETE FROM @BETA  
WHERE ID IN (SELECT B.ID from @ALPHA A right join @BETA B ON  A.ID= B.ID
             WHERE A.ID is NULL )
          OR ID IN (SELECT C.ID FROM @CHARLIE C INNER JOIN @DELTA D ON C.ID=D.ID)

-------------------Using Exists--------------------
 DELETE FROM @BETA  
 WHERE Exists (SELECT B.* from @ALPHA A right join @BETA B ON  A.ID= B.ID
               where A.ID is NULL )
 OR Exists (SELECT C.* FROM @CHARLIE C INNER JOIN @DELTA D ON C.ID=D.ID)
```

**Note:** I have used Sql table variables instead of Normal table.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `not exists`/`exists` for both.  I am not sure what "as well as excludes the records obtained by the inner join of CHARLIE and DELTA tables".

If you want to delete records where *both* conditions are met, then

```
DELETE B FROM BETA B
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ALPHA A WHERE A.id = B.ID
                     ) OR
          EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CHARLIE C INNER JOIN
                       DELTA D 
                       ON C.ID = D.ID
                  WHERE B.ID = C.ID
                 ) ;
```

If you don't want the `CHARLIE`/`DELTA` records to be excluded, then use `AND NOT EXISTS` rather than `OR EXISTS`.